# What is the behavior of thumbnails in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, thumbnails

In order to update all my thumbnails I rendered standard sized previews for all my pictures overnight, having read somewhere that this was the asiest way.

But to my surprise, there are still thumbnails that only become rendered when I scroll down to them. What's going on with this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is just how Lightroom works. The thumbnails fill in/render as you scroll down through the Library Grid. As far as I know the thumbnails in the Library module are built off of the embedded JPEG thumbnail and not using the standard sized previews that you generated - so that didn't do anything to help this situation.